# Next.js 13 + Firebase Hosting "not found" browser response

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am trying to follow all the available resources online to deploy a Next.js 13 app to Firebase Hosting, but am not able to find a solution; tons of outdated/conflicting info out there. There's [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting) Vercel example that doesn't work for me, but also seems to be using the `pages` structure instead of the SSR default `app` structure I am using. Firebase has a (brief) official doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs), but it also seems to be using the `pages` directory since they reference `getServerSideProps` which it looks like is a `pages` structuring usage. Maybe I am wrong on this point, and I should be using `getServerSideProps` directly in my app? Clearly Firebase has support for Next.js 13, since the [recent Github releases for tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases) makes many references to Next.js 13.

I initial built an app following [this guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-full-stack-app-with-nextjs13-and-firebase/) with some slight variations for my own structure styling, and the app works great locally, but when I deploy this app to Firebase hosting (only), the site is simply giving a "Not found" as a response:

[image]

I then scaled back and built a smaller app from `npx create-next-app`, and tried deploying that with hosting. After deploying to hosting, I am getting the different error screen (ugh) :

[image]

Now my head is spinning a bit and don't know what to go for *next*. Searching the web comes up with a ton of people using the `pages` structure, so now I am worried that maybe Firebase isn't the best solution for me now that I am moving to Next.js from CRA.... I have been using Firebase for years so don't want to lose all those features!!

Has anyone else had these issues while booting up an app with Next.js 13 on Firebase? Should I be using Vercel instead of Firebase for Next.js 13? Any help here would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of firebase-tools (12.2.0–12.2.1) contain a deployment bug. If you use that version, downgrade (`npm i -g firebase-tools@12.1.0`) or use this deploy command (`FIREBASE_FRAMEWORKS_BUILD_TARGET=production firebase deploy`). https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5896

This way I got SSG+SSR working with the app router!
Firebaser on Reddit commented that app router should be fully supported. https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/13fbxvh/comment/jkefwpp/

With the pages router, I got SSG working but SSR gives me Internal Server Errors for some reason.

Deploying a tiny test app already takes >5 minutes. My experience with Vercel is much faster, it should be possible to use Firebase SDK there aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I actually ended up moving to Vercel instead and have been having a much smoother experience for obvious reasons (its their product). From my reading it seems the Firebase team is still working on some of the updates to Next.js 13 SSR default behavior. I will check them out again for future projects when they catch up a bit!